# Is there a way to specify how text gets wrapped in React native Text component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a way to specify line break mode in react native to the Text component?

By default Text Component wraps text by words(ie if it can't fit a word it wraps it to next line). I want to wrap text by characters(ie it should display as many characters it can from the word and move to next line)

For example:
We can specify implement this in iOS by setting lineBreakMode to UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap on UILabel. I am trying to achieve something like that.

Answer (score 6):

Please try this code

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap',flexShrink: 1}}>
   <Text> You miss fdddddd dddddddd You    missfddddddddddddddasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasds</Text> </View>
```

Comment: I do not want word wrap, i want character wrap ie lets say their is space to fit only 10 characters and word length is 12 characters then it should show 10 characters of the word and move remaining 2 two characters to next line.

Comment: What you have mentioned above wraps words to next line.

Comment: I know the solution you have provided and it wraps text by words. I am looking for wrap by characters.

Comment: @Kishoretheju have u try flexshrink

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174252/discussion-between-hardik-bar-and-kishoretheju).

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i tried flexShrink also. Not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use similar feature on third party library component, checkout if it supports `multiline` property in some way.

In case of `Card.Title` of `react-native-paper`, property called `titleNumberOfLines` does the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

Use flexWrap as **hardik bar** said:

> **flexWrap** controls whether children can wrap around after they hit the
>   end of a flex container

Here is sample expo [link](https://snack.expo.io/SkHbs3vM7)

Comment: Only question owner can approve! :P